# Excel VBA userform calculations

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible that the results of calculations in a userform appear automatically at the moment I introduce the required input data rather than having a button for calculation?

i.e.: I have Textbox1 which asks for amount, textbox2 asks for tax, and textbox3 shows de result val(textbox1) * val(textbos2). It's possible that textbox3 shows the result when I'm introducing data both in textbox1 or 2 without waiting to enable a Commanbutton to "calculate"?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give this a try...

Place the following code on UserForm Module.

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
If Me.TextBox1 <> "" Then
    Me.TextBox3 = Val(Me.TextBox1) * Val(Me.TextBox2)
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! Thanks so much